# Replace NAs with Row Minimum for Selected Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, min, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a dataframe with several types of columns (character, numeric, ID, time,etc.). I'll provide a simple example as follows:

```
m <- data.frame(LETTERS[1:10], LETTERS[15:24],runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10),runif(10))
x<-c("Col1","Col2","Col3","Col4","Col5","Col6","Col7")
colnames(m)<-x
m<-as.data.frame(lapply(m, function(x) x[ sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.75, 0.25), size = length(x), replace = TRUE) ]))

> m
   Col1 Col2       Col3       Col4       Col5       Col6       Col7
1     A    O 0.09929126 0.40435352 0.15360830 0.03830400 0.80157985
2     B    P 0.50314123 0.81725456         NA 0.07054851 0.65521042
3     C <NA> 0.75798665         NA 0.04483692 0.54671014         NA
4     D    R 0.96825047 0.01875140 0.07383107         NA 0.04498563
5  <NA>    S 0.47079716 0.04181401 0.21423046         NA 0.55493444
6     F <NA>         NA         NA         NA 0.33702657 0.54989260
7     G    U 0.71947656         NA         NA 0.99142181 0.69548691
8  <NA> <NA> 0.90518907 0.20661633 0.65788523 0.05534330 0.78420756
9     I    W 0.79208514 0.63233902         NA 0.72085080         NA
10    J    X 0.39093317 0.97107464         NA 0.86417719 0.39890170
```

For Col3-Col7, if there are less than 3 NAs, I want to replace it with the row minimum from Col3-Col7, otherwise keep the NAs there. So, I'd want the dataset to look as follows:

```
> m
   Col1 Col2       Col3       Col4       Col5       Col6       Col7
1     A    O 0.09929126 0.40435352 0.15360830 0.03830400 0.80157985
2     B    P 0.50314123 0.81725456 0.07054851 0.07054851 0.65521042
3     C <NA> 0.75798665 0.04483692 0.04483692 0.54671014 0.04483692
4     D    R 0.96825047 0.01875140 0.07383107 0.01875140 0.04498563
5  <NA>    S 0.47079716 0.04181401 0.21423046 0.04181401 0.55493444
6     F <NA>         NA         NA         NA 0.33702657 0.54989260
7     G    U 0.71947656 0.69548691 0.69548691 0.99142181 0.69548691
8  <NA> <NA> 0.90518907 0.20661633 0.65788523 0.05534330 0.78420756
9     I    W 0.79208514 0.63233902 0.63233902 0.72085080 0.63233902
10    J    X 0.39093317 0.97107464 0.39093317 0.86417719 0.39890170
```

So every row except row 6 had the values imputed by the minimum value in each row for columns3-7.

In my actual dataset, for every row between columns 18:27, if there are less than 4 NAs, replace with the row minimum for the columns 18:27, otherwise keep all the NAs.

I've tried using the dplyr pipes/mutate/replace method, but I'm not sure how to do it for a subset of columns (I'm under the impression you can only specify one column with mutate/replace). Some of the logic I've tried including in the if statement includes

```
rowSums(is.na(.[18:27]))<4 & rowSums(is.na(.[18:27]))>0)
```

I've seen the rowMins function in the matrixStats package, but I'm just wondering if I can do this with dplyr/dataframe and not matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a `tidyverse` approach where you reshape the data and group by `Col1` and `Col2` and the re build the data. As we will use pipes, we can also create the new variables with `mutate()` and evaluate the condition you want after creating `Flag` variable and also computing the min value. Next the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
m <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "<NA>", "F", "G", 
"<NA>", "I", "J"), Col2 = c("O", "P", "<NA>", "R", "S", "<NA>", 
"U", "<NA>", "W", "X"), Col3 = c(0.09929126, 0.50314123, 0.75798665, 
0.96825047, 0.47079716, NA, 0.71947656, 0.90518907, 0.79208514, 
0.39093317), Col4 = c(0.40435352, 0.81725456, NA, 0.0187514, 
0.04181401, NA, NA, 0.20661633, 0.63233902, 0.97107464), Col5 = c(0.1536083, 
NA, 0.04483692, 0.07383107, 0.21423046, NA, NA, 0.65788523, NA, 
NA), Col6 = c(0.038304, 0.07054851, 0.54671014, NA, NA, 0.33702657, 
0.99142181, 0.0553433, 0.7208508, 0.86417719), Col7 = c(0.80157985, 
0.65521042, NA, 0.04498563, 0.55493444, 0.5498926, 0.69548691, 
0.78420756, NA, 0.3989017)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

The code:

```
#Reshape
m %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(Col1,Col2)) %>%
  group_by(Col1,Col2) %>% mutate(MinVal=min(value,na.rm=T),
                                 Flag=sum(is.na(value))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  mutate(value=ifelse(is.na(value) & Flag<3,MinVal,value)) %>%
  select(-c(MinVal,Flag)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   Col1  Col2     Col3    Col4    Col5   Col6   Col7
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A     O      0.0993  0.404   0.154  0.0383 0.802 
 2 B     P      0.503   0.817   0.0705 0.0705 0.655 
 3 C     <NA>   0.758   0.0448  0.0448 0.547  0.0448
 4 D     R      0.968   0.0188  0.0738 0.0188 0.0450
 5 <NA>  S      0.471   0.0418  0.214  0.0418 0.555 
 6 F     <NA>  NA      NA      NA      0.337  0.550 
 7 G     U      0.719   0.695   0.695  0.991  0.695 
 8 <NA>  <NA>   0.905   0.207   0.658  0.0553 0.784 
 9 I     W      0.792   0.632   0.632  0.721  0.632 
10 J     X      0.391   0.971   0.391  0.864  0.399
```

Comment: How can I do this without grouping by other columns? Apparently, there are some duplicates for some columns, so I need to do it rowwise.

Comment: You can check duplicated rows and then omit with `filter()`.

Comment: @helpmewithexcel If you have duplicated rows it is still possible to group vars, you have to create an index for duplicated rows!

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you, I need to treat the whole dataset as if every observation is unique, even if there are duplicate combinations for Col1 and Col2. I don't want to omit duplicates or group by..

Comment: @helpmewithexcel  Yes, it is possible to manage all rows without filtering even if there are duplicates

Comment: Ok, got it. For some reason I was under the impression the similar column combinations would aggregate together/merge as one observation so the minimum of only one of those rows would be looked at but it'd be distributed for both rows.

Comment: @helpmewithexcel Yes you are right, at any moment data is removed. So, the solution worked for you?